# How high can I tune my G string without it breaking?

Tags: tuning, bass-guitar

I've been learning this [bass solo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T60DXXHcT-A) by Jean Baudin. And he has an 11 string bass. I have a 4 string. Only at a few parts in the song, he plays notes higher than my highest F on the G string.

So my question is: How high can I tune my G string without it snapping?

Comment: You're learning a bass solo (never saw the point in learning solos, myself) that's been written for a different instrument.  I would just look for a different piece to learn, instead of risking (as slim says) limb and instrument.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Be very, very careful. You're worrying about the string snapping. You should also be worrying about damaging the neck of your instrument.

A bass string will go very tight without snapping. If it does snap, you risk injury. I've had a nasty cut just from a guitar string! If the instrument breaks, you also risk injury -- and you've broken your instrument.

Instruments are designed to carry a certain tension. Exceeding that tension can damage them badly. Keeping them below that tension for long periods is also not a great idea.

The right way to get a higher pitch is to use a narrower gauge string.

String manufacturers produce charts telling you what tension strings exert at various pitches. [Here is a link to D'Addario's](http://www.daddario.com/DAstringtensionguide.Page).

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand those charts. But I will take your advice on not doing it. haha